# Как изменить определенную часть поля?

Tags: запрос, php, mysql

Имеется поле "item", которое содержит: "0;0;0". Вопрос: как мне изменить в запросе, например, только второй ноль на 1 или же на 2, посредством php соответственно?

Comment: А может надо сразу в базе поменять без php?

Comment: Не надо хранить в одном поле много значений. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Согласен с @Etki, лучше хранить значения в разных колонках, чем так мучиться с разделителями, к тому же, храня в разных колонках, можно будет легко делать сортировку по разным колонкам, чего нельзя будет сделать со строкой с разделителями...

Comment: @Nik555, просто это получается 3 лишних поля

Comment: @XenK, как будто в эти данные не сохраняете в другом поле. Как будто это не получается много лишнего геморроя.

Comment: @Etki, эти данные я сохраняю в одном поле, а так придется в 3-х.

Comment: @XenK ну да, ну да, нельзя же так расточительно обращаться с полями, они же кончиться могут.

Comment: @XenK, сколько у вас полей в таблице? С вашей точки зрения, можно вообще хранить все данные в одном поле строкой с разделителями, но зачем вам тогда БД? Можно обойтись и простым файлом :) Для того и создана БД, чтобы разложить все по полочкам (полям) и делать удобную выборку данных. @Etki, многие наверное полагают, что большое кол-во полей, это не есть хорошо, но это не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простое решение, это использовать php-функцию: `explode("Разделитель", "строка")`.

Например:

```
$str = "0;0;0"
$arrElement = explode(";", $str);
```

Теперь переменная (массив) `$arrElement` содержит три элемента.
И если вы, например, хотите поправить второе значение и записать сроку, то это можно cделать так:

```
$arrElement[1] = 2; //Поменяли значение на 2.
$newStr  = implode(';',$arrElement);
```

*P.S. Этот вариант прост в понимании и реализации, но не является лучшим решением. Лучшее решение - это написать регулярное выражение.*

Answer (score 2):

выборка из бд $item

```
$items = explode(';', $item);
$items[1] = $items[1]+1;
$item = implode(';',$items);
```

записать в бд $item